# can't control from js with video.js with videojs-youtube to work on ipad

Tags: ipad, youtube, video.js

I'm using videojs-youtube, and while I can get the video player to display in youtube, if I try to control it programattically the player breaks (goes black) on ipad.  Not sure if this is a problem with video.js or  videojs-youtube.

I have created a simple test to just play the video on load. When this executes on ipad, the player turns black, no video or controls are available.  I don't see any errors when debugging the ipad  w/safari on my connected mac.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <video id="vid3" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360">
  </video>

  <script src="js/vendor/video.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/vjs.youtube.js"></script>
  <script>
  videojs('vid3', { "techOrder": ["youtube"],  "src": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ" }).ready(function() {
      this.play();
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Apple does not allow 'autoplaying' of video on ios devices. I **was** able to do other things such as `this.on("timeupdate"...`

Comment: Can you please share more about your solution here?

Comment: While the items mentioned above seemed to reduce the intermittent issues I was getting, it did not eliminate them. I ended up removing the videojs and videojs-youtube libraries and using the youtube native player.


I had entered an issue on the videojs-youtube github site, which was closed without any comments. [link](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/issues/78) It's possible that library updates since I last tested may address the problem, I haven't tested in over 5 months.